# How does the compiler internally translate a closure that contains a closure?

Tags: c#, linq, closures

*The code is partially modified and added so that you can practice the contents of the **EFFECTIVE C# (COVERS 6.0)** book.*

---

I have a closure that contains a cloure. To understand that code, I tried How the compiler translates it internally. However, it failed to bind `c.importantStatistic` to the delegate at the end.

`LeakingClosure` is the code from the book, `ResourceHogFilter` and `CheapNumberGenerator` are what I additionally wrote to compile `LeakingClosure`.

```cs
private static IEnumerable<int> LeakingClosure(int mod)
{
    var filter = new ResourceHogFilter();
    var source = new CheapNumberGenerator();
    var results = new CheapNumberGenerator();

    var importantStatistic =
        (from num in source.GetNumbers(50)
            where filter.PassesFilter(num)
            select num).Average();

    return 
        from num in results.GetNumbers(100)
        where num > importantStatistic
        select num;
}
```

```cs
public class ResourceHogFilter
{
    public bool PassesFilter(int num)
    {
        return num < 30;
    }
}
```

```cs
public class CheapNumberGenerator
{
    public IEnumerable<int> GetNumbers(int size)
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < size; i++)
            yield return i++;
    }
}
```

First, The Query Expression was changed to the Method Call Syntax.

```cs
private static IEnumerable<int> METHOD_LeakingClosure(int mod)
{
    var filter = new ResourceHogFilter();
    var source = new CheapNumberGenerator();
    var results = new CheapNumberGenerator();

    var importantStatistic = source
        .GetNumbers(50)
        .Where(num => filter.PassesFilter(num))
        .Average();

    return results
        .GetNumbers(100)
        .Where(num => num > importantStatistic);
}
```

I then tried the following to make it appear similar to what the compiler would translate:

```cs
private static IEnumerable<int> COMPILER_LeakingClosure(int mod)
{
    var source = new CheapNumberGenerator();
    var results = new CheapNumberGenerator();

    var c = new Closure();
    c.filter = new ResourceHogFilter();

    var importantStatistic = source
        .GetNumbers(50)
        .Where(new Func<int, bool>(c.filter.PassesFilter))
        .Average();

    c.importantStatistic = importantStatistic;

    return results
        .GetNumbers(100)
        .Where(new Func<int, bool>(c.importantstatistic)); // compile-time error
}
```

```cs
private sealed class Closure
{
    public ResourceHogFilter filter;
    public double importantStatistic;
}
```

However it failed to bind `c.importantStatistic` at the end. Because, `Average()` returns a `double`, `results.GetNumbers()` returns an `IEnumerable<int>`.

What code did the compiler correctly represent the `COMPILER_LeakingClosure` class and the `Closure` class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [SharpLab.io](https://sharplab.io) to see what the compiler lowers your lambdas into. Usually, the lowered code will contain a bunch of names with unusual characters and is quite hard to read, but it is not impossible.

`LeakingClosure` is translated into:

```
public static IEnumerable<int> LeakingClosure(int mod)
{
    <>c__DisplayClass0_0 <>c__DisplayClass0_ = new <>c__DisplayClass0_0();
    <>c__DisplayClass0_.filter = new ResourceHogFilter();
    CheapNumberGenerator cheapNumberGenerator = new CheapNumberGenerator();
    CheapNumberGenerator cheapNumberGenerator2 = new CheapNumberGenerator();
    <>c__DisplayClass0_.importantStatistic = Enumerable.Average(Enumerable.Where(cheapNumberGenerator.GetNumbers(50), new Func<int, bool>(<>c__DisplayClass0_.<LeakingClosure>b__0)));
    return Enumerable.Where(cheapNumberGenerator2.GetNumbers(100), new Func<int, bool>(<>c__DisplayClass0_.<LeakingClosure>b__1));
}
```

`<>c__DisplayClass0_0` here is analogous to your `Closure` class - both are used to capture the `filter` and `importantStatistic`. The difference here is that it also has two methods that contains the bodies of each of your lambdas:

```
[CompilerGenerated]
private sealed class <>c__DisplayClass0_0
{
    public ResourceHogFilter filter;

    public double importantStatistic;

    internal bool <LeakingClosure>b__0(int num)
    {
        return filter.PassesFilter(num);
    }

    internal bool <LeakingClosure>b__1(int num)
    {
        return (double)num > importantStatistic;
    }
}
```

Making the names more readable and improving the formatting, we get the following output:

```
private static IEnumerable<int> COMPILER_LeakingClosure(int mod)
{
    Closure c = new Closure();
    c.filter = new ResourceHogFilter();
    CheapNumberGenerator cheapNumberGenerator = new CheapNumberGenerator();
    CheapNumberGenerator cheapNumberGenerator2 = new CheapNumberGenerator();
    c.importantStatistic = Enumerable.Average(
        Enumerable.Where(
            cheapNumberGenerator.GetNumbers(50), new Func<int, bool>(c.WhereLambda1)
        )
    );
    return Enumerable.Where(
        cheapNumberGenerator2.GetNumbers(100), new Func<int, bool>(c.WhereLambda2)
    );
}

private sealed class Closure
{
    public ResourceHogFilter filter;
    public double importantStatistic; 
    
    internal bool WhereLambda1(int num)
    {
        return filter.PassesFilter(num);
    }

    internal bool WhereLambda2(int num)
    {
        return num > importantStatistic;
    }
}
```

Comment: Using SharpLab.io, you can experiment with various things :D

Answer (score 1):

When the compiler creates nested classes internally, it includes local variables as well as lambda expressions that use local variables.

```cs
private static IEnumerable<int> COMPILER_LeakingClosure(int mod)
{
    var source = new CheapNumberGenerator();
    var results = new CheapNumberGenerator();

    var c = new Closure();
    c.filter = new ResourceHogFilter();
        
    var importantStatistic = source
        .GetNumbers(50)
        .Where(new Func<int, bool>(c.PassesFilter))
        .Average();

    c.importantStatistic = importantStatistic;

    return results
        .GetNumbers(100)
        .Where(new Func<int, bool>(c.GreaterThanImportantStatistic));
}
```

```cs
private sealed class Closure
{
    public ResourceHogFilter filter;
    public bool PassesFilter(int num) => filter.PassesFilter(num);

    public double importantStatistic;
    public bool GreaterThanImportantStatistic(int num) => num > importantStatistic;
}
```